# What are the advantages of creating an Odoo module as opposed to forking it?

Tags: odoo

We are interested in using Odoo but we would need to modify it slightly for our use case, for instance modifying partner by adding fields, and integrating with an external system.

Is it best to fork it or to make a module with the changes in? The changes would be quite specific to our use case and existing system so it's unlikely it would be useful to anyone else as a module/app.

My thinking is that by forking it would be easier to stay up to date with Odoo - we just have to pull in changes from upstream occasionally. It seems like with a module you would end up with lots of stale code that's difficult to update because you've moved it outside the source tree.
It also seems like it would be easier to deploy because you have all the code in one place rather than two.

Comment: Make own module and not ruining odoo's original module to prevent any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As from my POV and according to many years of ERP - experience, it is the best advice to implement those kind of changes **always** in an own module (inheriting all the required standard components) and leave the standard untouched. This applies also for very specific customizations as well as for general improvements.

This procedure provides you with the best flexibility in installing, updating, distributing and maintaining your code while not being touched when updates to the standard modules are carried out on the target systems.

You will also be able to share and move your code between dev/test/prod systems and applying a version control on it.

Please always make sure to be in line with valid license obligations applying to your code (especially when inheriting standard modules).

Hope this helps ;-)